# best match from smaller array to larger array. (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays

I have two arrays filled with doubles, the first array is smaller than the second array, there is no exact match between the arrays but I am trying to see if there is a way to show where the nearest match is in both arrays.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to clarify what "best match", "exact match", and "nearest match" means, in regard to two arrays?  Perhaps with an example?

Comment: I am just guessing you are looking for is faiss https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss just check it out if you see this is what you want

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you want to find the first index from which the smaller array matches exactly a subset of the larger array? for example:
[2,3], [1, 5, 2, 3, 6] ==> at index 2.

```
double big[N], small[M]; // M <= N
bool found = False;
... // initialize arrays..

for (int i = 0; i <= N; ++i){
    int j = 0;
    while (small[j] == big[i+j]){
        j++;
        if (j >= M){
            found = True;
            break;
        }
        else if (i+j >= N) return -1; //didn't find a solution.
    }
    if (found) return i;
}
```